# Pdf files access denied

Tags: 18.04

I am running Ubuntu 18:04 & I have a problem opening some pdf files, I get a message saying access denied/file does not exist. I have previously been able to open them, something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

permission errors are happened due to simply PERMISSIONS

right-click on that file -> select properties -> permission tap
and set the options in an appropriate way

or

in terminal :

```
sudo chmod o+w /path/of/ur/file/file.pdf
```